# How to modify a variable in an event listener

Tags: java, event-listener

i want to modify the variable user passed to a constructor and then modify it in an event listener. the application consists of two window one for login and the main window for the application. I want that the user is recognized by the main window. So when the user log in successfully his info are stored in a user object. the problem is that when the user clicks on the login button the user variable is not seen in the inner class ButtonAction.
for example:

```
public class LoginDialog extends JDialog{
public LoginDialog(User user) {
       


....
}
private class ButtonAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                             ................
                             setUserInfo(user)//here user is not visible
                }
}


}
```

```
    
    public class Main {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private LoginFrame loginFrame;
    private JLabel mainFrameLabel=new JLabel("Sign In");
    User user=null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        
        
        
        
        LoginDialog loginDialog = new LoginDialog(user);
        loginDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        loginDialog.setModal(true);
        loginDialog.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Stampo info studente:");
        System.out.println(user);
        loginDialog.dispose();
        
        if(user.getLoggedIn()) {
            mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Frame");
            mainFrame.setBounds(300, 300, 450, 300);
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            
            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setBounds(10, 10, 426, 243);
            mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
            mainPanel.setLayout(null);
            
            
            mainFrameLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
            mainFrameLabel.setBounds(70, 102, 252, 33);
            mainPanel.add(mainFrameLabel);
            
            
            mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent we) {
                    
                    mainFrameLabel.setText("Sign In");
                    
                    user.setLoggedIn(false);
                    user=null;
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                    
                    mainFrameLabel.setText("Sign In");
                    
                    user.setLoggedIn(false);
                    user=null;
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                
                
            });
        }
}
}
```

I get an error "user cannot be resolved to a variable" on setInfoUser(user).How can i solve it?
As you can see i have summerized.
I have tried several things. But i haven't solved the problem.
P.s.there are some other errors but i am not interested.

Comment: Define the variable as an instance variable in your class and then in the constructor you you assign the User to this variable.

Comment: Make ButtonAction an inner class of LoginDialog so it has access to user.

Comment: I have to pass it to another jFrame. User must be visible to a login frame and a main frame.The user parameter of LoginDialog comes from main application.

Comment: My is only an excercise. I want that a user is rcognized from the main application after he is successfull logged in.

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, you need to post more of it. I suggest that you post the body of constructor for class `LoginDialog`. I also suggest that you post code that calls that constructor. Is class `ButtonAction` an inner class of `LoginDialog`?

Comment: yes ButtonAction is an inner class. as you can see i have posted more.